# How to display all lines in file that matching a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How to display all lines in file that  matching a regular expression? This match() method returns null to me.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const file = fs.readFileSync('./myfile.txt', 'utf8')
let res = file.match(/error/gi)
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Well, you should probably first load/read the file, no? :)

Comment: Oh, sorry. Thank you for a suggest). I edit the code. But now, js returns me not a string with "error" but an array that looks like "'Error', 'Error', 'error', 'error', 'error', 'error', 'Error',"

Comment: Hmm, it seems that you're asking a different question now :] Keep in mind that Stack Overflow  is not for step-by-step debugging in comments. If the result of a method call surprises you, then it's a good idea to read more about that method, what it does and how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to read the file:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const text = fs.readFileSync("./mytext.txt");
const textByLine = text.split("\n")
textByLine.forEach( line => {
  if (line.match('/error/gi')) {
    console.log(line);
  }
});
```

Comment: Nice. But js returns me not a string with "error" word, but an array that looks like "'Error', 'Error', 'error', 'error', 'error', 'error', 'Error',"

Comment: if (line.match('/error/gi'))
{
  console.log(line);
}
If not found will return null

Comment: Great. Thank you.